# what is the macaroon max length

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, macaroon

In an LND node, what is the max size, in bytes, of a macaroon. If there is no explicit max length, what can you reasonably expect to be the size of your macaroon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macaroon consists of three parts:

1. The header: Identifies the macaroon and contains three fields.

   - The `version`: 1 byte, always set to `0x02` in `lnd`
   - The `location`: variable length string, always set to `"lnd"` in `lnd`
   - The `identifier`: variable length binary data, contains `protobuf` serialized data in `lnd` containing the **permissions** of the macaroon. More on that later.
2. The `caveats`: Restricts the capabilities of the macaroon. This is a variable length list of strings. `lnd` currently only implements two possible restrictions, the `time-before` and the `ipaddr` restriction.

   - Example with maximum characters:

     ```
     ["time-before 2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00", "ipaddr 255.255.255.255"]
     ```

     Which is roughly 70 bytes plus some encoding overhead.
3. The `signature`: An `HMAC-SHA256` hash, so 32 bytes plus encoding overhead.

## The permissions

As mentioned above, the macaroon identifier contains a list of permissions. Currently this just contains a `protobuf` serialized list of `{Entity string, Action string}` pairs that correspond to [permission sets in `lnd`](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/56af0e15224ffd65d2fe3ebf7e595fa3a6b07d31/rpcserver.go#L201). For example, the pair `{Entity: "info", Action: "read"}` would give a user read-only access to informational calls.

These permissions make it a bit tricky to estimate the maximum size of a macaroon in `lnd`. At the moment, the maximum number of distinct entity/action pairs that exists is 17, which is given to the automatically created `admin.macaroon`. That admin macaroon currently is around 280 bytes in size.

But soon, you will be able to customize the permissions of a macaroon even further by [specifying individual URIs that are allowed to be accessed](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/pull/4463). A user could could then, for example, add a permission pair of `{Entity: "uri", Action: "/lnrpc.Lightning/ExportAllChannelBackups"}` to a custom macaroon.

Just for fun, I went ahead and created a [maximum-sized macaroon with all currently available URIs](https://gist.github.com/guggero/c1ffcc309ef0ad8079196e3ba6d02b50) which turned out to be **4041** bytes in size.

From that, I would summarize that limiting user input when uploading a macaroon to 4096 or 5120 bytes should cover almost all cases of custom macaroons.